# PHPExcel Excel export works at localhost and test server but in production server not working properly

Tags: php, phpexcel

My exporting to excel codes are working greatly with my localhost and test server but in production server it goes crazy.

Something like that in exported excel:

```
ÐÏà¡±á;þÿ 
þÿÿÿþÿÿÿ ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ » ÌÑB°=¼%r8X"1ÜCalibri1Ü¼Calibriàõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À àõÿ À à À à È “€ÿ’â8ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ€€€€€€€€€ÀÀÀ€€€™™ÿ™3fÿÿÌÌÿÿffÿ€€fÌÌÌÿ€ÿÿÿÿÿÿ€€€€€ÿÌÿÌÿÿÌÿÌÿÿ™™Ìÿÿ™ÌÌ™ÿÿÌ™3fÿ3ÌÌ™ÌÿÌÿ™ÿfff™–––3f3™f333™3™3f33™333…é WorksheetÁÁgæ®ü£CihazImei_NoGsm_NoKampanyaActivation_Date Fatura_Tutari Temlik_Tutari » ÌÑ*+‚€Áƒ„&ffffffæ?'ffffffæ?(è?)è?¡"dXX333333Ó?333333Ó?U} } }  }  } } } } $ } $ } $ } $ } 

$ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ } $ }   $ } !!$ } ""$ } ##$ } $$$ } %%$ } &&$ } ''$ } (($ } ))$ } **$
```

I think something with my server configurations. I could not find anything. What can it be?

```
<?php

$rowIndex = 2;
$currentId = '';
while ($foundRows = mssql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $colIndex = 0;
        foreach ($data_cols as $col_name) {
        $val = $foundRows[$col_name];
        $activeSheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($colIndex, $rowIndex, $val);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyleByColumnAndRow($colIndex, $rowIndex)->getFill()->setFillType(PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID);
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyleByColumnAndRow($colIndex, $rowIndex)->getFill()->getStartColor()->setARGB('FFFFCC');
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyleByColumnAndRow($colIndex, $rowIndex)->getBorders()->getAllBorders()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);

    ++$colIndex;}
    ++$rowIndex;


}
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="temlik.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Is it displaying that on screen, or is it offering the file for download?

Comment: This is shown in the downloaded file

Comment: ARe there any leading spaces before the ÐÏà ?

Comment: WHat version of PHPExcel are you using? because that temlik.xls file that you have linked to contains information that PHPExcel's Excel5 Writer simply doesn't write (specifically the SummaryInformation and DocumentSummaryInformation OLE streams)... so I have difficulty believing that PHPExcel is generating that temlik.xls file, unless it's a modified version of the library

Comment: I am using @version  1.7.4, 2010-08-26. You can believe it. It is generated by PHPExcel. Maybe i made "save as.." it before upload. Because of it seems not generated by PHPExcel

Comment: Make sure there is no extra spaces before your <?php similar with '[the other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814114/phpexcel-output-is-garbled)'

Comment: i think its character encoding problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write ob_clean() just before the last line below , i was having same problem got resolved by this

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="temlik.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
ob_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```