# PHPExcel output is garbled

Tags: php, phpexcel

Im trying the simple examples -01simple.xls- that come with PHPExcel
im getting garbled output.
It (LibreOffice) wants to import the file
it thinks the char set is Western Europe DOS/OS2-861.icelandic
and the output is like this

╨╧αí▒ß
■                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ╗
╠╤B░=╝%r8X"1▄ÉCalibriα⌡ 
    ╗
╠╤*+éÇü┴âä&ffffffµ?'ffffffµ?(Φ?)Φ?í"dXX333333╙?333333╙?U}$  }$  }$  }$  ²
²
²
²

> ╢@gg     
>   Root

Its probably something straightforward , but Ive no idea

Comment: That definitely looks like its garbled: it doesn't look like an Excel file at all. But there's no information there to help me diagnose the problem

Comment: Open the file in a text editor. Look for spurious whitespace characters (carriage returns, line feeds, tabs) at the beginning or end of the file

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853285/phpexcel-outputs-garbled-text
This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

try reupload phpexcel with the transfer type in the ftp set to auto.

Comment: go through all required and included files of your own, and make sure there is no extra spaces, HTML, or whitespace above or below PHP tags.

Comment: you saved me 'make sure there is no extra spaces,'

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure to remove all of the BOM's for the files. This script works great for it! http://code.google.com/p/bomremover/