# PHPExcel outputs garbled text

Tags: php, phpexcel

Like many others out there i have had my fair share of issues trying to download an Excel file output by PHPExcel.
What happened in my case was whenever I wanted to download a file using

```
$obj->save('php://output')
```

i always used to get garbled text in my excel file with a warning saying my file was corrupt. Eventually i resolved the issue. The problem being i had a

```
require('dbcon.php')
```

at the top of my php script. I just replaced that with whatever was there inside `dbcon.php` and it worked fine again. 
Though the problem is solved i would really like to know what caused the problem. It would be great if anyone out there could help me out with this one.

Thanks.

Comment: The PHP error messages injected right into the Excel file?

Comment: nope i dont think it is the error message. i am going to verify what @mark baker said below and get back in sometime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get that error - you should follow the advice we always give in that situation: you use a text editor to look in the generated file for leading or trailing whitespace, or plaintext error messages - and then in your own scripts for anything that might generate that such as echo statements, blank lines outside `?>` `<?php`, etc.

Another way of testing for this is to save to the filesystem rather than php://output and see if you get the same problem: if that works, then the problem is always something that your own script is sending to php://output as well.

Clearly you had a problem along those lines in your dbcon.php file. This can be as simple as a trailing newline after a closing `?>` in the file...

Comment: turns out a stupid 2 spaces after the `?>` in `dbcon.php` caused the problem. I feel stupid now.

Answer (score 0):

Tanmay.

In situations like your's, there can be couple of reasons for broken output:

- in file dbcon.php can be a whitespace before opening or ending php
  tag, so that produce some chars to output and can make file broken
  (this is reason for using only opening tag in php 5.3+);
- maybe file dbcon.php wasn't found by require, so you got error message in otput;
- any other errors or notices or warnings in dbcon.php, because presence of global vars from current file..